# JavaCV for rtmp streaming with Vitamino library for video playbback gives unsatisfied linking error in Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, rtmp

I am developing an application which will broadcast live stream using RED5 server.
I am using java CV 0.3 and Vitamino Libarary.
Java CV 0.3 to send stream to RED5 server and Vitamino to play live stream.

When i run my app it gives me unsatisfied linking error below :-

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library 
"libopencv_core.so" needed by "libjniopencv_core.so"; caused by library "libopencv_core.so" not found
```

If I will remove the vitamino library it works.

Please suggest me any solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer version of javacv - 0.9 try it. I also heard there is a problem with mac libraries in the current version so you might need to try snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Answering my friend.
I have finally solved the problem by doing this :-

Copy all files from libs>armeabi to libs>armeabi-v7a and it will work.